# Is there any mistake in this Code ? if it is let me know?

Tags: python, calculator

```
a = int(input("Enter Your First Number="))
b = int(input("\nEnter Your Second Number="))

def cal():
    sum = a + b
    sub = a - b
    mul = a * b
    div = a % b

cal()    
print("\nAddtion of Two Number is =" , sum)
print("\nSubtraction of Two Number is =" , sub )
print("\nMultiplication of Two Number is =" , mul  )
print("\nDivision of Two Number is =" , div  )
```

> I can't find the exact output I'm a beginner So guide me please,

Comment: Mistake #1: This code is python yet you added Java and C++ tags for no reason

Comment: Mistake #2: You are trying to access function-local variables outside of that function, where there are no longer in scope

Comment: downvoted into oblivion... might want to edit that title and give more details on the problem/errors youre actually having `cal = lambda: (a+b,a-b,a*b,a%b)` then `sum,sub,mul,div = cal()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return the values in order to use them outside the function

```
a = int(input("Enter Your First Number="))
b = int(input("\nEnter Your Second Number="))

def cal():
    return a + b, a - b, a * b, a % b

add,sub,mul,div = cal()    
print("\nAddtion of Two Number is =" , add)
print("\nSubtraction of Two Number is =" , sub )
print("\nMultiplication of Two Number is =" , mul  )
print("\nDivision of Two Number is =" , div  )
```

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't call a variable `sum` because you overwrite the builtin [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the function return the values:

```
a = int(input("Enter Your First Number="))
b = int(input("\nEnter Your Second Number="))

def cal():
    sum = a + b
    sub = a - b
    mul = a * b
    div = a % b
    return sum, sub, mul, div

sum, sub, mul, div = cal()    
print("\nAddtion of Two Number is =" , sum)
print("\nSubtraction of Two Number is =" , sub )
print("\nMultiplication of Two Number is =" , mul  )
print("\nDivision of Two Number is =" , div  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant acces function variables outside of function. PLace print statements inside a function or return values from the function as mentioned below.